# Kubuntu 22.04 not showing recent used applications and files

Tags: kubuntu, 22.04, launcher

Kubuntu 22.04 stop showing recent application and files in the application launcher dashboard menu, after upgrading from Kubuntu 20.04.

-I tried different application launcher menu but the problem still present.

-Delete the .config not solving the issue.

-But when I create new user everything is ok

Any help would be great! If I someone guided me to fix it without creating new user and move my data.

Thank you.

My system

Kubuntu 22.04
OS Kernel 5.15
CPU AMD Ryzen 7 Gen 3
RAM 64 GB

Comment: Try deleting `.local/share/plasma`?

Comment: I did, issue still present

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution [here](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=119324&start=15).

I solved the problems by editing:

```
~/.kde/share/config/kdeglobals
```

And added the settings:

```
[Recent Applications]
MaxEntries=20
UseRecent=true

[Recent Documents]
MaxEntries=25
UseRecent=true
```